# f# finding the indexes of a string in a char array

Tags: f#

Hey all i am new to F#

I am trying to find the starting indexes of all the occurrences of a string in a char array.

e.g.
char array ['a';'b';'b';'a';'b';'b';'b';'b';'b';'a';'b']

would return 0 and 3 and 9  if you were searching for the string "ab"

Comment: Can you show where you are stuck?

Comment: I have tried to use List.FindIndex but that only returns the first index

Comment: should it return you 9 as well?

Comment: This can be solved in a number of ways - perhaps it is best to first look at the different algorithms that you can use so that you have some idea of what you're trying to do: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using recursive functions:

```
/// Wraps the recursive findMatches function defined inside, so that you don't have to seed it with the "internal" paramters
let findMatches chars str =
  /// Returns whether or not the string matches the beginning of the character array
  let rec isStartMatch chars (str: string) =
    match chars with
    | char :: rest when str.Length > 0 ->
      char = str.[0] && (isStartMatch rest str.[1..(str.Length - 1)])
    | _ -> str.Length = 0
  /// The actual function here
  let rec findMatches matchedIndices i chars str =
    match chars with
    | _ :: rest ->
      if isStartMatch chars str
      then findMatches (i :: matchedIndices) (i + 1) rest str
      else findMatches matchedIndices (i + 1) rest str
    | [] -> matchedIndices

  findMatches [] 0 chars str
```

Not the most efficient as it iterates over characters twice if they're part of a match, but that's not really a big worry.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to do a complete example here, so here is the hint:

```
let rec match (l:char seq) i= 
    match seq.tryFindindex ... (*the part you have already done goes here*)with
    |None -> []
    |Some(t) ->i+t::(match (Seq.skip t l) (i+t)
```

Basically, we just repeatedly apply the `Findindex` until it stops matching.

Comment: let rec find (l:char seq) i= 
        match Seq.tryFindIndex(fun a -> String.Compare(a,searchSeq)=0) with
        |None -> []
        |Some(t) ->i+t::(find (Seq.skip t l) (i+t))

It says none is not an int which is true. How do i allow that result?